# Universal google analytics pass variable cross domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to pass variable on domain number 1 and get this variable on domain number 2 by using universal Google analytics. In old version of Google analytics I used to do this task very easily:

Domain 1:
set:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, 'some_name', 'some_id', 1)
```

and send:

```
window.open(pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(item.redirectUrl()), '_blank')
```

Domain 2 get the item:

```
var some_var= pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(1);
```

My question is how to do this on Universal Google analytics.
I need to 'translate' this code to new syntax and new methods, because i can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (not with Universal Analytics anyway). This used to work because the data was stored in a cookie and transported across domain boundaries as an url parameter when you used the linker methods.

UA does not store data in Cookies (except client id), it stores custom dimensions (where you would store visitor level information) on the server and retrieves the values for the reports via the client id. Since there is no channel back from the tracking server to the website you cannot retrieve values the way it used to work with getVisitorCustomVar.

Of course nothing stops you to write your own cookie and send the value as url parameter, but it just wont work with UA.